# WooCommerce custom order action does not work with trash status

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I want to use woocommerce hook **woocommerce_order_status_changed**.
I want to fire something when new status of order is **trash**.

I used this function, which is working good for rest order statuses, except **trash**.

This is my code:

```
function custom_order_actions ( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status ){
  $order = new WC_Order($order_id);

  if ($new_status == 'trash') {
    // Do something
  }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'custom_order_actions', 99, 3 );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`woocommerce_order_status_changed` can not pick up the `trash` status since it's not one of the registered statuses on woocommerce [according to their github page](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/55fd39d49316acda5ea0389ad0df702e143e3449/includes/wc-order-functions.php#L93).

However, you could use `wp_trash_post` action hook instead!

```php
add_action('wp_trash_post', 'custom_order_actions');

function custom_order_actions($order_id)
{

    if ('shop_order' == get_post_type($order_id)) {
        $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
        // Do something
    }
    
}
```

[`wp_trash_post`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_trash_post/)

Let me know if it works for you!